# Can’t see google maps on my device and emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing an app with a partner. My partner can see the Google Maps in the app, however, I can’t see it in the device and emulator. I don’t think is a code problem because my partner can see it, maybe it is something I have to download on my device?

I already install Google Service also and nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details and be more specific. Currently there is no problem described or it is too general.

Comment: Is it possible that there are some exceptions that are caught and not reported that are preventing it from working in your environment. There's little to go on so I'm afraid it will be difficult to assist. Could you provide more information: for instance, SDK version, OS version of the emulator on your system, OS version on your device and the working device to see if that could be issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You don't have to have restrictions on your key otherwise only who created project can see map. Go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key) and edit the options. Sorry for image in Italian

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this documentation first https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

What you may be doing wrong is that you have not entered your debug android studio SHA-1 key in your google developer console while putting restriction on to your key and wait for at least 10 minute after doing any updation on your developer console. If this doesn't solves the problem then please share some more details about the code integration and your key restriction than only anyone here can help you getting out of this problem.